# Как получить новые данные из списка словарей?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, list, словари

Я делаю запрос к API и получаю в ответ список словарей:

```
[{'fullName': 'd KsrionohC', 'reportedTitle': 'iagtcpcocOinPfrf lirinAnce u', 'effectiveDate': 1638397365511, 'tranShares': -4499, 'tranPrice': 320.6, 'tranValue': -1437179.49, 'directIndirect': 'D', 'tranCode': 'S'}, 
 {'fullName': 'neAarJun dg', 'reportedTitle': 'irtceoDr', 'effectiveDate': 1617488519947, 'tranShares': -9899, 'tranPrice': None, 'tranValue': None, 'directIndirect': 'D', 'tranCode': 'M'}, 
 {'fullName': 'uenAaJ dngr', 'reportedTitle': 'ecoDrtri', 'effectiveDate': 1591113566625, 'tranShares': 9854, 'tranPrice': 50.29, 'tranValue': 491036.1, 'directIndirect': 'I', 'tranCode': 'M'}]
```

Я делаю несколько таких запросов и в какой-то момент в этот список может добавиться еще один словарь. Мне нужно получить этот словарь. У API нет WebSoket, нет WebHook. Есть SSE, но он не поддерживает нужный мне метод. Поэтому, обновления я могу получать только через GET-запросы.

Как мне без записи в БД получать только обновлённые данные?

Comment: можете дать определение понятию `"обновлённые данные"` ? Если изменяются значения в ячейках ранее существовавших записей - это обновленные данные или нет?

Comment: Нет, ячейки не изменяются. Только добавляются новые словари. Старые данные статичны. Но возврат неупорядоченный, они могут быть не на своих местах ( возврат похож на сет и в этом сете могут быть новые данные(словари)) . Я пытался сделать set и найти пересечение , но так как в списке словари, это не удалось.

Comment: можно ли считать, что одно из полей уникально идентифицирует запись?

Answer (score 3):

Можно сравнивать хеш кортежа значений словарей.

Пример данных:

```
In [24]: data1 = \
    ...: [{'fullName': 'd KsrionohC',
    ...:   'reportedTitle': 'iagtcpcocOinPfrf lirinAnce u',
    ...:   'effectiveDate': 1638397365511,
    ...:   'tranShares': -4499,
    ...:   'tranPrice': 320.6,
    ...:   'tranValue': -1437179.49,
    ...:   'directIndirect': 'D',
    ...:   'tranCode': 'S'},
    ...:  {'fullName': 'neAarJun dg',
    ...:   'reportedTitle': 'irtceoDr',
    ...:   'effectiveDate': 1617488519947,
    ...:   'tranShares': -9899,
    ...:   'tranPrice': None,
    ...:   'tranValue': None,
    ...:   'directIndirect': 'D',
    ...:   'tranCode': 'M'}]

In [25]: data2 = \
    ...: [{'fullName': 'd KsrionohC',
    ...:   'reportedTitle': 'iagtcpcocOinPfrf lirinAnce u',
    ...:   'effectiveDate': 1638397365511,
    ...:   'tranShares': -4499,
    ...:   'tranPrice': 320.6,
    ...:   'tranValue': -1437179.49,
    ...:   'directIndirect': 'D',
    ...:   'tranCode': 'S'},
    ...:  {'fullName': 'neAarJun dg',
    ...:   'reportedTitle': 'irtceoDr',
    ...:   'effectiveDate': 1617488519947,
    ...:   'tranShares': -9899,
    ...:   'tranPrice': None,
    ...:   'tranValue': None,
    ...:   'directIndirect': 'D',
    ...:   'tranCode': 'M'},
    ...:  {'fullName': 'uenAaJ dngr',
    ...:   'reportedTitle': 'ecoDrtri',
    ...:   'effectiveDate': 1591113566625,
    ...:   'tranShares': 9854,
    ...:   'tranPrice': 50.29,
    ...:   'tranValue': 491036.1,
    ...:   'directIndirect': 'I',
    ...:   'tranCode': 'M'}]
```

---

решение:

```
new_hashes = set([hash(tuple(x.values())) for x in data2]) - \
             set([hash(tuple(x.values())) for x in data1])

new_records = [x for x in data2 if hash(tuple(x.values())) in new_hashes]
```

---

результат:

```
In [46]: new_records
Out[46]:
[{'fullName': 'uenAaJ dngr',
  'reportedTitle': 'ecoDrtri',
  'effectiveDate': 1591113566625,
  'tranShares': 9854,
  'tranPrice': 50.29,
  'tranValue': 491036.1,
  'directIndirect': 'I',
  'tranCode': 'M'}]
```

Comment: А зачем так сложно? Разве нельзя просто `not in data1`?

Comment: @PavelDurmanov, наверное можно...